# Trouble bridging remote access VPN connection to LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10, ping, bridged-adapter

I am using Radmin VPN to create a remote access VPN between my home and office computer. On the office computer, I created a network bridge (in windows) to bridge the VPN network connection with the LAN connection so that I can use remote desktop and SSH to access other computers on the office network from my home computer.

To do this, I first created the bridge by selecting the VPN connection, followed by the LAN connection and selecting "Bridge Connections". This created a network bridge which had an IP address on the same subnet as the other office computers. I then gave my home computer an additional IP address in the VPN connection that is on the same subnet as the office network computers. So far, I am able to ping the office computers and access Remote desktop and SSH from home. However, I am unable to directly ping or RDP into my office computer (the one hosting the VPN connection) when the bridge connection is enabled. When I try to ping it's LAN IP address, I get a "TTL expired in transit." error.

What does this mean and what can I do to fix it so I can also ping and RDP into my office computer? Everything else seems to work fine except for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is you're trying to connect using the Radmin IP that is no longer valid. Maybe you can try to find a valid IP for your office computer within the Radmin network IP range or use a separated machine for rdp the office computer.